# Convert SQL Datetime to C# Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datetime, asp-classic

I have null able DateTime database field and its corresponding class's DateTime? variable in C# code.

I want to convert that value in normal date.

e.g. I want to convert From

**2013-12-12 00:00:00.000  to 2013-12-12**

Any help is admirable. Thanks.

Comment: For `DateTime`s "2013-12-12 00:00:00.000" is "2013-12-12" - i.e. they have the same value, but different representations as strings

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 4):

```
if(dt.HasValue)
{
    newDt = dt.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

I suppose that dt is the value you get from your database. If it is not null, then I set the string newDt equal to the  expression you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's just unclear what do you mean by "normal" date, but I assume you want to format it in a proper way. DateTime object extends the ToString() method to provide format information:

```
DateTime? dt;
//your code here
string output;
if (dt != null){
  output = ((DateTime)dt).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DateTime.Parse(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in combination with [`.ToShortDateString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So for your example:

```
DateTime.Parse("2013-12-12 00:00:00.000").ToShortDateString()
```

Its without catching a `ParseException` or something else, so you have to do it by yourself!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ToShortDateString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
yourDate.ToShortDateString();
```

with `yourDate` a `DateTime` varible.
It will remove the time part of your datetime (ie `00:00:00.000`) and only keep the Date part.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateToDisplay = new DateTime(2009, 6, 1, 8, 42, 50);
String formattedDate = dateToDisplay.ToShortDateString()
```

You can also set the culture here to get in whatever format you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

var s = ((DateTime)ExpirtyDate).Date;
string ans = s.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

Take the value in a datetime variable and use the following to just get the date and not time:

```
DateTime Mydate = DateTime.Now;// instead of datetime.now get the value form sql 



DateTime newformat = Mydate.Date;//then use this to get only date and remove tome
```

alternatively you can use the `mydate.ToShortDateString()` function as well